# Qt slot simultaneous disconnect and call from different theads

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread

I'm newbie to Qt. I haven't found an answer in a reasonable time and decided to ask here.

I have a thread, let's call it `Thread1` with Qt object which have a connected slot. Signal is emitted from the same thread (`Thread1`).
And I'm disconnecting this slot from another `Thread2`.

Is this operation thread safe?
Are there any problems, if a signal is emitted and slot is disconnected exactly at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the docs, it looks safe to me:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html

> Note: All functions in this class are reentrant, but connect(), connect(), disconnect(), and disconnect() are also thread-safe.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#disconnect

> Note: This function is thread-safe.

Also make sure that you are using Queued Connections when you are connecting the signal of one thread to the slot of another.  The Auto-connect may misbehave (and do direct connection) if both objects happen to be in the same thread during the time of the connection.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: More about Thread Safety:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-reentrancy.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html

Comment: Well. I've read this, but I'm not sure about my question. Look. What does it mean - "thread safe function"? - it means that a function has some king of a mutex, which prevents simultaneous execution with another mutex-protected function. But if one function has mutex guards, and another one doesn't, their simultaneous execution is not thread-safe although one of them is thread-safe. So, I want to know - whether signal/slot execution procedure protected from simultaneous execution with disconnect function or not. Does documents implies this or not? Because it doesn't look obvious to me

Comment: Well if you ask `Is this operation thread safe?` people assume you know what `thread safe` means.